# Store the value displayed in the EDIT menu and pass it as a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, gridview, datagrid

I'm using a viewgrid (MVC ASP.NET and C#) and everytime i clik on **EDIT BUTTON** for a specific row, all that information is displayed in a different page and then, i can modify whatever i want and save the changes.

The problem is that i want to store the values that appeared in the edit page at first and also the new values because i want to trigger a STORED PROCEDURE and pass all the values as parameters (the old ones and the new ones). Do you get me?
Here an example:

[image]

**This is my CONTROLLER code:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            User user = dbContext.GetUserById(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        // POST: User/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, [Bind] User user)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    dbContext.UpdateUser(user);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(dbContext);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

---

**This is what my UpdateUser function does:**

```
public void UpdateUser(User User)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE_USER", con)
        {
            CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", user.NAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LASTNAME", user.LASTNAME);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", user.CODE);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }


}
```

EDIT:
This is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_USER
(
    @NAME varchar(255) = '',
    @LASTNAME varchar(255) = '',
    @CODE varchar(255) = '',
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE MAPPINGTABLE
    SET NAME= @NAME,
    LASTNAME= @LASTNAME,
    CODE= @CODE
    WHERE CODE= @CODE;
END
GO
```

I'd like to pass all the previous values that appeared when i click on EDIT, i mean: i should create 3 new parameters called:
OLD_NAME, OLD_LASTNAME, OLD_CODE.

Answer (score 0):

> pass all the values as parameters (the old ones and the new ones)

While you required the old values inside the Stored Procedure, so you can make a query before the new value gets updated without passing the old values from the controller.

Comment: Hey pal, how are you?
Sorry i do not fully understand your point. Can give me an example?

Comment: If I understood correctly. You need old values in a stored procedure. If so then you can add a query `SELECT * FROM User Where ID = Your_Edit_ID` and store its value to SQL variables. Now, you have both the values old (_fetched by db query_) and new (_which you are already passing from code_)

Comment: Everytime i click on EDIT button i get a view where i can modify the data, then click on SAVE and it is updated in the database. (i'm triggering a stored procedure). So, in this case i am passing the new values *but* i want to pass some of the previous values that appeared when i click on EDIT button the first time too, do you get me?

Comment: Where should i use that query of yours? i'm kinda lost right now :/

Comment: You need to write a query to your **UPDATE_USER** stored procedure.
And also share your purpose of old values.

Comment: Pal, i have updated my question. I do not how to pass the content of the old values and the new values aswell. Take a look at my thread

Comment: In your update stored procedure, you need to pass the Id (Primary Key) of the table. And add the below code in SP before update statement.
`DECLARE @Old_NAME     VARCHAR(255) = '',
        @Old_LASTNAME VARCHAR(255) = '',
        @Old_CODE     VARCHAR(255) = ''

SELECT @Old_NAME = Name, @Old_LASTNAME = LastName, @Old_CODE = Code FROM MAPPINGTABLE WHERE Id = @Id`

In these new variables, you will get the old values.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {

        var Details = new ModelClass()
        {
            ModelClass = db.tablename.Where(a => a.id== id).ToList()

           
        };
        return View("Method name", Details );

        
    }
```

And in MVC View your edit button must be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id}) |
```

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!.
What is this actually doing?